# How to adjust top menu bar size?

Tags: menu

I accidentally clicked something that enlarged the top menu bar. I have no idea how I did this but just want to change it back. Picture included below:[image]

Comment: look for "scale" or scaling in the monitor/desktop/display system settings, report back what that is set to.

Comment: Or if you could, then download Ubuntu tweak from app Center. It will provide you options to modify various font size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For new user and Tweaking purpose, **`unity-tweak-tool`** is very helpful to change such settings.

Can be installed by following command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Goto **Appearance>Font** :
[image]

In you can customize following:

- **Default font** : Ubuntu 11
- **Text scaling factor** : 1.00
- Or **Restore Defaults** to set default settings

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to change the font size of the top bar text using the suggestion from @Pandya, but I did find an alternative. For Ubuntu 18.04, go to `Settings > Universal Access` and then enable `Large Text`. This changes the top bar text (as well as window title bars)

Comment: In my case, default already on, simply toggle off -> on in `Large Text` button then it work.

Answer (score 0):

Download ubuntu tweak. [Here](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/10/ubuntu-tweak-reached-to-086-version.html) are the instructions for ubuntu 14.04.
Now launch it. Under the Tweaks tab select the text button. Now, the first option will be Text Scaling factor. Restore it to default.

Comment: If that did not work, Try to set all the settings to defaults

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04, activity bar size and fonts become smaller occasionally, I could not find how. In the tweak screen suggested by @Pandya, all are seems normal but when I have changed text scaling factor from 1.0 to 1.1, it has become bigger than the default, and reduced 1.1 to 1.0 back then bar and content turned the default and visible.

Comment: Consider that this is not really an answer to the OP question: you may open a new question for your problem. I must add that probably you don't need to open it because your problem is already dealt here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact