# Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor

Tags: nvidia, fonts, restart, interface

So I was configuring VS code on my Notebook when suddenly I noticed that my interface font got really small on my desktop, terminal and files.

I use Gnome Tweaks Tool to increase my scaling factor to 1,15 , but, even though it was active, the font stayed tiny.

The solution I found was moving my scaling factor, which instantly fixed my font issue, however, every time I restart my Notebook the font gets tiny again and I have to repeat the process.

I tried reseting my font configuration using this command, but had no success.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```

I also tried using the command

```
dconf reset -f /
```

Finally, I tried using dconf-editor, but still had no success altering the
font rendering DPI or changing the scaling factor.

All of the steps I mentioned fixed my fonts temporarily, but the issue still persists when I restart my Notebook

I am out of ideas and even considered getting a fresh Ubuntu install by now...

My video card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 GPU

Comment: Even in lock screen the text appears to be scaled abnormally

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Update 2020-10-07**

The bug is now fixed, you can get it with `apt` and remove any workaround you had chosen.

**Original answer**

It's a recently introduced bug in Mutter which is the default window manager for Gnome Shell.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440

It seems to affect mainly Nvidia cards.

It was fixed in Pop!_OS by removing the patch named "x11-Add-support-for-fractional-scaling-using-Randr.patch"
https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/1170
https://github.com/pop-os/mutter/commit/a912c7fc25f4797047790fc5df1711eeb31af282

Ubuntu devs did not say how they will resolve this but at least they acknowledged the problem and someone is assigned to it.

The only known workaround for now is what you described: in Gnome Tweaks, change the scaling factor to something else and back to the original value. Unfortunately, as you noted this will be needed after each login and even after each restart of Gnome Shell (ALT+F2, r).

Comment: Switching from NVIDIA binary driver to X.Org X Server driver and rebooting as suggested in Sujit's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1269431/1099709) worked for me. I prefer it over the other workarounds because there's no need to reapply it or write a script.

Comment: Keep in mind that switching from Nvidia to Nouveau driver can have much more impact on your system. For example, no Vulkan support in Nouveau, many Steam games will be much slower or plainly not work. In general, performance and compatibility with current graphic cards generation is still a [problem](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia-nouveau-2019&num=1). To me it is not worth the trade-off compared to a 4 lines script running automatically on each login without any impact on the system.

Comment: I see something similar with an Intel video card, although only affecting the Shell itself. Changing scaling and then back returns display to normal

Comment: There is [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440/comments/17) for this bug: downgrade buggy packages `sudo apt install libmutter-6-0=3.36.1-3ubuntu3 gir1.2-mutter-6=3.36.1-3ubuntu3` and hold current versions `sudo apt-mark hold libmutter-6-0`. Don't forget to subscribe on launchpad issue to unhold package when fix comes up.

Comment: I use this "large text" trick https://superuser.com/a/869720/157532

Comment: "The bug is now fixed, you can get it with apt" -- get what exactly?

Comment: @C-F Just keep your packages up-to-date through `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. This will automatically install a mutter version with the fix since it was integrated in Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @stefg-bz In fact, I already had a newer version of affected library, but I still had the issue (not with all UI, only with the top bar, Ubuntu 20). Switching to the open source driver helped me (as suggested here:https://askubuntu.com/a/1269431/924496). Not a perfect solution though.

Answer (score 28):

**EDIT 2020/10/07**

The bug has been fixed in the package `mutter (3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2)`, available via `apt`.

**Original answer**

Inspired by this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1269399?noredirect=1) I implemented a temporary workaround in my machine. I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04.1 with GNOME Shell 3.36.4.

This does NOT fix the font size in GDM login screen, but only after the login. This trick simply avoids to repeat an annoying sequence of commands after every reboot.
Of course this trick may be useful only till the bug in Mutter is fixed.

1. Create a script (I put it in `~/.local/bin`) with the following content:

   ```
   sleep 5s
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.01
   sleep 0.5s
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.00
   ```

   '1.01' it's just a number to trigger the changes, it may be any value. I decided to use a value very near to the final one.
   '1.00' is the value that I eventually want. Feel free to put your target value. Same thing for the sleep times, you can change them.
2. Make it executable running:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/.local/bin/fix-font-size.sh
   ```
3. Run the script (I named it `fix-font-size.sh`) at boot. For this reason I run Startup Applications Preferences app and created a new item with the following command:

   ```
   bash -c "/home/username/.local/bin/fix-font-size.sh"
   ```

   Also see the screenshot for reference (where "Modifica programma d'avvio" means "Startup Applications Preferences"):

   [image: add command to startup applications]
4. Save and you should have a correct size font after login without manually inserting commands in the terminal or by GUI.

Comment: For our English readers, "modifica programma d'avvo" is Ubuntu's built-in `Startup Applications Preferences` app.

Comment: Though the bug is supposedly fixed, I still see this problem. Every time I reboot, the font reverts to smaller than 1. I have to turn off/ turn on "Large Text." To do that, I squint and sort of guess at where the Universal Access icon is in my title bar. Using the scrpt per your instructions, it works like a charm.  Thank you!  BTW - in case anyone else is wondering, the "Large Text" setting in Universal Access appears to be a scaling factor of 1.25. So in my script, I am setting factor to 1.00, then back to 1.25 (the equivalent of turning off large text, then turning it back on again).

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440):

You can downgrade libmutter package temporarily as a workaround:

```
sudo apt install libmutter-6-0=3.36.1-3ubuntu3 gir1.2-mutter-6=3.36.1-3ubuntu3
sudo apt-mark hold libmutter-6-0
```

Remember to unhold after fix comes out!

Comment: How to unhold ?

Comment: I think it is the best and easiest option until fix comes out! Thanks!

Comment: @IvanP You can use sudo apt-mark unhold libmutter-6-0

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** Only for PC's having a NVIDIA graphic card.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS yesterday and faced this exact same problem. This and whenever I close and re-open my laptop lid, the wallpaper gets corrupted, but that's a whole other question. After some messing around I figured out how to solve this issue. All you have to do is change the graphics driver from **NVIDIA Binary Driver** to **X.Org X Server** in the *Additional Drivers* section under *Software & Updates* (Remember to click *Apply Changes*, this will take a while). After the changes have been applied, restart your PC. Doing this fixed the issue and the other bug I mentioned above.

[image]

Cheers!

The method above is a permanent fix. If you want to use the **NVIDIA** driver, I think you're gonna have to wait for the developers to release a patch.

---

I also found this temporary fix (for the bug in question, not the one I mentioned above). You'll have to do this every time you restart. This is if you really wanna keep your **NVIDIA** driver.

Go to *Settings>Universal Access* and enable & disable **Large Text**. That'll show you how Ubuntu is supposed to look.

[image]

Cheers Again!!

Comment: Switching from NVIDIA binary driver to the X.Org X Server driver then rebooting fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @BrandonMiller glad I could help :)

Comment: Not the solution if you use an Intel graphics card (and yes, it affects me to). Best workaround: a startup script as indicated in the answer by 
Lorenz Keel

Comment: @vanadium, I see... thanks for letting me know

Comment: Changing the graphics card driver is definitely not the solution, as it can have way more impact on the system than the bug itself. Besides, people who bought a (expensive) specific graphics card and installed the official driver did it for some reason and removing the whole device functionality due to some fonts bug in the desktop manager is not acceptable at all.

Comment: @JoséL.Patiño you don't have to change it to X.Org, those were the only two choices for me why I wrote this answer. Now there are more, just switch it to the latest NVIDIA driver and the problem should probably get fixed, otherwise just wait for Ubuntu 20.04.2, a fix to mutter has been pushed for that version, but will be released only in Feburary 2021. There is a way to get the fix on 20.04.1 itself, but that could lead to more bugs so I wouldn't recommend it until they officially release it.

Answer (score 5):

As this is a bug, as outlined nicely [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1269399/558158) by stefg-bz, we will have to wait a bit until it is fixed. In the mean time, you can use a workaround, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1269402/558158) by Lorenz Keel, that automatically changes the scaling factor and sets it back when you log in. Here, I provide my implementation of the workaround, which does not require installing additional tools and having a separate script.

**1 Create a `.desktop file` in your autostart folder.**

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/workaround_font_scaling.desktop
```

**2 Paste the following contents in the text file**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/sh -c "sleep 1 && gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.2" 
Name=Fontissue
StartupNotify=false
Type=Application
```

Adapt the contents on the `Exec=` line to your needs.

- Change `1.2` in `org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.2` to the font scaling factor you use yourself.
- Change `1` in `sleep 1` to a higher value if the setting is not (always) applied correctly after login. `sleep 1` provides a delay of 1 second before the `gsettings` command kicks in. For example, `1.5` would make the delay 1.5 seconds.

**3 Save the file and close the editor**

Answer (score 1):

So I've seen you folks trying hacky ways to make it work, but the one solution I found that proven to work well "making it permanent" is this

Install Gnome Tweak tools

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

look for installed app `"Tweaks"`

In tweaks go to `Fonts > Scaling factor` .. set it to `1.0` or whatever you like.

Reboot .. this should make that change permanent

Comment: I'm already using the tweak tool, but the problem comes back again restart :(

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and had the same issue. I am using a Nvidia 2080 Ti with a 4k 42" TV. The text was too small and title bars was the same way. I fixed my issue by changing the display scale settings from 100% to 200%. You can find this under settings/display. This fixed my issue. I restart the computer too to make sure the settings saved and they do. Hope you resolve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately 200% makes everything too big on my 1080p display, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading 20.04 yesterday, I had the problem of fonts staying too large, not too small, but I have a 4k monitor and tweak my fonts differently.

What worked for me (and what survives reboot) was to turn on Fractional Scaling in settings and use a 125% scaling.  I also turned off Large Text in Accessibility and set Gnome Tweaks Font Scaling to 1.0.  I don't know if that is mandatory but it works for me as I previously was using Font Scaling of 1.25. The bottom line is that Fractional Scaling now works for me on my nVidia GeForce GTX Titan X, whereas previously it didn't.  Is this a fix in the recent upgrade?  I have no idea.

Comment: Fractional scaling doesn’t work for me, it glitches my screen and turns everything barely readable unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here that seemed to appear in one of the updates in the past week or so. UI text (clock, window titles) and menu bar upper tray icons are too large initially, when using an Nvidia card with a 4K monitor (this is a laptop and the problem does not occur if the monitor is disconnected). My workaround is what someone mentioned above where I have to flip the accessibility setting "Large text" on and then back off to get the text back to normal. We'll probably see a fix in about two years, knowing Ubuntu, but fortunately the workaround is easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your NVIDIA Driver
go to software & updates, Tab Additional Drivers and change it to X.org
this solve my problem
and wait for a patch from Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the ways to temporally fix this problem, you can turn large text on and off in the accessibility pull down and this will solve the problem until next restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a discrete Nvidia card on Linux then you may use an integrated Intel one (aka APU if your processor supports graphics) to avoid display and text scaling problems with installed Nvidia driver. The following commands may do a trick for you:

```sh
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
# if any errors occurs you may try to use the following command
# it's the latest open-source, long-term driver version for the current moment
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455 # if no errors on the above command - skip
$ sudo prime-select intel
$ sudo reboot
```

So on the restart of the system it should work as expected and when you type in the terminal `sudo prime-select query` it will show that Intel profile is used.

Last but not least, Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't suffer from text scaling issues with Nvidia cards (at least Nvidia RTX 2060 mobile & GTX 1660 Ti mobile work perfectly) but do from display scaling.

Comment: I don't have an integrated intel gpu... Only geforce 1080. This solution does not apply to most desktop.

Comment: @francogp yes, indeed. I mentioned it above to avoid confusion, thanks.