# Top bar scrunched/smooshed Ubuntu 20.04 (GNOME)

Tags: 20.04

I run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the GNOME desktop. Within the last few days the top bar was suddenly smooshed (see image below). I am not sure how it happened and it occurs on all monitors. How do I fix it?

[image: Top bar Ubuntu 20.04 smooshed]

Notes:

- I have an NVIDIA GPU
- This is not an issue anywhere else on the desktop, just the top bar

Comment: It's a bug affetting some user that have Nvidia GPU. This is only one of the questions in Askubuntu for this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact/

Comment: It is also affecting other users like me, having an Intel Graphics card. Could you indicate what card you have? (add the info to your post, use "edit").

Comment: Workaround available in that question. However, I expect developpers will correct this pretty soon.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for the tips. I have a Nvidia GPU, but turns out they coincidentally implemented a fix overnight!

Comment: @vanadium funny, now the problem is back!