# Desktop font changed suddenly, yet font size in tweaks at default values

Tags: unity, gnome, fonts

The size of the folders on the desktop and the upper (gnome?) bar both suddenly changed yesterday.

As you can see in the picture, the text `Tweaks` (on the top bar) and `example` (on the desktop) are smaller than the font in the file navigator.

I checked this post ([How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)) but curiously, the values seem unchanged and are still at their default values. (See pic)

Which is the relevant parameter for the upper menu and desktop icon font size?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to Settings, then Screen Display and select 'turn on fractional scaling' worked for me.

Note that the actual scaling remained at 100%, but changing that option seemed to make the difference.

No idea what the root problem is, but another thread said a bug has been identified after a recent update: [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)

Comment: thanks! Great contribution for your first post :-)