# my username turns into dots on the login screen

Tags: login-screen, text, username

This error suddenly appeared with no reason, my username in the login screen is written like "ez..." instead of "ezzat" like if the text is overflown.
Also, there is a slide bar on the right even though there is no user other than this shown user.

[image]
Any help?

Comment: Currently there is a bug related to the libmutter-6-0 package that is affecting a lot of user. This bug consists in fonts smaller (and sometimes bigger) than normal. I have the same issue in my login screen (my username does not fit the box) and even after login the font size is not ok. See here for the bug status: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440 If you don't want to implement some workarounds, you should only wait for an update of the libmutter-6-0 package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, actually I've noticed that when I change font to large in the accessibility menu and reset it again it returns to normal.

Comment: In the question you mentioned, there is something similar with the tweaks.I think my case is different, I find this bug only in the login screen, but maybe connected somehow to the other bug because I have also an NVIDIA card.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the links above, the issue may appear in different forms. The fact that changing temporarily the settings and then restoring the original value fixes the box size, brings me to think that the problem is in the bugged libmutter package :-)

Comment: I hope they fix the package soon, anyways , thank you for your time.