# Bug of tiny text interface when computer starts

Tags: interface, text

All of a sudden, when the computer started, the log in screen was strange and the text almost unreadable so small it was. I typed the password and all the system text remained very tiny and unreadable. I went to universal access in configs and changed to large text, the problem was solved, but soon after came back. I have to keep going to config to change to "enable large text" and when the problem comes back "disable large text". I am looking for a more definitive solution for this strange system interface problem.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: In the `Displays` settings panel, what resolution do you have set? Do you have a 4K video monitor?

Comment: Probably you faced the bug that is described here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1269090/1037999 You can either wait that libmutter package will be updated to fix the bug or implement some of the workarounds described in that link.

Comment: In the other question, you will see a temporary method to automatically change and restore the font scaling setting during log in. However, that does not fix the small login screen. I expect a fix will come quite soon.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've changed the nvidia driver config as suggested by the link <https://askubuntu.com/q/1269090/1037999> and it seems to have solved the problem.