# Gnome logs in with display scaling problem

Tags: gnome, 20.04, scaling, hdpi, gnome-tweaks

I have a problem where after log in some elements of the Gnome interface appear very large, while the applications still render at the correct size.

Going into Gnome Tweaks, Fonts, Scaling and changing scaling factor from 1.00 to 1.01 fixes the problem. Then you can immediately put it back at 1.00 and the scaling remains good. After log out / log in the problem comes back.

The problem began suddenly after some apt packages upgrades (not sure how to know which one(s) caused the problem.

My specs are:
Ubuntu 20.04.1
Gnome 3.36.3
X11
All system packages updated to latest versions.

How do I fix this permanently so that I don't have to do the Tweaks workaround every time I log in?

Some screenshots attached for reference.

Thanks.

[image: Wrong scaling]

[image: Correct scaling]

[image: Setting for workaround]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that thread. My problem has similar symptoms and the same workaround but the behavior is opposite. In my case, the scaling gets enabled when it should be off. In their case, it appears the problem prevent them to achieve the correct scaling they need. I will keep monitoring that post as a potential fix may or may not fix my problem as well.

Comment: After performing some tests, I can confirm that my problem relates to the same bug as described in the post [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)