# Weird display scaling problem after login

Tags: gnome, 20.04, display, display-resolution

I have a very odd display behaviour since installing some updates a few weeks ago. When my laptop boots, the display looks as though it has been scaled to around 80% of the normal display size. For example, the font on a terminal window is now small enough to be uncomfortable to read. If, after logging-in, I open the Settings, set the display scaling to any value (I usually use "Scale 200%" but the actual value doesn't matter), then apply, and then immediately revert the setting from the dialog that pops up, the display goes back to normal scaling, my fonts are the right size etc.

I have *no* hypotheses for what's going on here! I've looked at the output from `xrandr --verbose`, but it's the same before and after I do the change scale/apply/revert hack. This behaviour persists through a reboot.

I believe that, around the time this started happening, I switched from the nvidia 440 drivers to nvidia 450. But switching back to 440 doesn't help, so I suspect that may be just a coincidence.

I'd welcome any suggestions as to where to start looking to figure out what's going on!

```
$ uname -a
Linux alder 5.4.0-45-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 26 13:38:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ nvidia-smi
Thu Sep  3 10:28:15 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.66       Driver Version: 450.66       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    598MiB /  4040MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1557      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                116MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2451      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                267MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2703      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              201MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Looks like it might be a duplicate of this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently [a recently introduced mutter bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440). See the bug report for temporary workarounds