# Unreadable font size in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: display, fonts

I had installed gnome-tweaks to play around the visual appearance of my ubuntu system however for some reason the fonts have become really small and strain the eyes.

I have removed the gnome-tweaks however the font size remain the same,this begins even before login.

Any idea how this can be corrected ( I have tried to increase the size but it reverts after i logout )

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you install gnome-tweaks again and show the font menu?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity i have added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 20.04 And up**

1. Install GNOME Tweaks from the Ubuntu Software app.
2. Open GNOME Tweaks.
3. Go to the **Fonts** Category.
4. Change the **Interface Text** to a more larger font size. (11 or more)
5. Save the changes.

**Other Methods:**
Reinstall OS. reinstall gnome-shell. reinstall ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Will try the steps, reinstalling the OS is an overkill for me

Comment: Also, some useful info for you: the default font size for ubuntu and gnome. (11 for Interface font, 11 for Document Text, 13 For monospace font, 11 for Legacy window titles.)

Comment: Apparently, the scaling factor changes the size i am facing issue with however it seems to be temporary and once i reboot, its gone.