# Font resizing on every boot

Tags: shortcut-keys, fonts

On my laptop display (1920 x 1080 resolution), the default font looks very small. So I have binded the <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> shortcut to the `increase text size`, under `shortcuts` section in settings. This does the job and the font size is increased, and everything looks good (font size wise).

But recently, I noticed that I have to increase the font size after every time I reboot my PC. After every reboot, it goes to the original tiny size (default size).

How do I increase the font size one and for all?

**EDIT 1**
I just noticed that the small size of font is only in the top bar, settings and the app drawer. Font in the web browser, text editor, desktop icons, terminal stick to the size I last set them to.

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.5` would set your scaling to 1.5. To revert it you can `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor`.

Comment: @starkus still on reboot it rolls back to default settings. Is there a way I could add this command to booting process?

Comment: I mostly use `alacarte` if i need to try startup settings for some reason. You could just create a launcher for the command and launch it via startup programs using gnome-tweak-tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact) There are some temporary workarounds in the answers, and the reason of the issue (bug in libmutter package)

Comment: @LorenzKeel the OP of that question, said that the font in terminal also got small. Which is not true in my case.

Comment: @LorenzKeel the temporary work around did work for me thanks

Comment: @Abhay-Patil Yeah, I know that your problem is a little bit different, but It seems that the bug in libmutter may appear in different ways (i.e. some people have big fonts, some people have small fonts). Glad that the workarounds fixed the problem, while waiting for an official fix in libmutter.

Comment: @LorenzKeel and apparently the temporary fix you provided doesn't work after I boot into Windows and then boot into Ubuntu again. If I restart and boot again into Ubuntu, it does work. But now after I boot into Windows