# Gnome interface is upscaled

Tags: nvidia, gnome, gui

I use Ubuntu 20.04.1, Gnome 3.36.3 on Lenovo ideapad L340 (UEFI, Dual boot with Win10)
GeForce GTX 1650 with nvidia-driver-440

My desktop UI (top bar, popups, Applications screen) and login screen are twice larger that they should be. But all other applications work correctly.

To fix this problem I tried:

1. To use open source driver - the problem is fixed, but I have very low performance with this driver.
2. To run with grub option acpi=off - the problem is fixed, but there's a lot of critical issues appears.
3. To set display scale to 200% and than revert - the problem is fixed until restart.
4. To reinstall Gnome with commands

   ```
   apt purge gnome-shell
   apt install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
   ```

   nothing is changed at all.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you are facing the issue described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact The OP talk about small fonts, but in some cases also big fonts may be explained by the bug in `libmutter`` package. There you can find the link to follow the status of the work on a new libmutter package release and some workarounds as well (while waiting for an official fix).

Comment: @vanadium It's helped. Thank you.