# Ubuntu 20.04 Big font on top bar

Tags: 20.04, fonts, scale-mode

I just made a reboot because I have got some upgrades and need to reboot.

After reboot, Ubuntu 20.04 the fonts of the top bar and filenames on the desktop are very big. Even the symbols for network and other things are big, so it may bee a scaling problem. Can't find anything in Settings or Tweaks (that I installed after the problem) that may explain this issue.

My desktop after upgrade and reboot:

[image: My desktop after upgrade and reboot]

Comment: Did you try Gnome Tweak Tool?

Comment: In the last month a lot of topic about font size issues have been opened in Ask Ubuntu. For example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact There is a bug in `libmutter` package that causes troubles (both small or big fonts). In that topic you can find the reference to the bug tracker https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440 and some workarounds as well (but for a definitive solution, you need to wait that the fix is released).

Comment: A fast way to understand if you have the bug in `libmutter`, is to go in Gnome tweak tool, change the scaling value to any value and then rechange it to the initial value: if the font comes back to normal size, it is likely that your last upgrade introduced the bugged version of `libmutter`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)

Comment: @Lorenz Keel . Thanks. The scaling factor under Tweaks-->Fonts--> scaling factor was 1.0. I change to 0.12, and it gets really smal, then back to 1.00 and it gets normal. :) /Cheers

Comment: Alt+F2 then enter 'r' (restart) as the command (this restarts the gnome-shell and the top bar dimensions are ok).  You need to do this after every new login.